# Adjust font size to fit text to frame in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign data merge to generate lots of filled-in pages. I have a specific text block which holds a name, but always needs to be on one line. Is there any way I can have InDesign automatically reduce the font-size if the text wraps?

Comment: Have you tried Google? I found this script with a 3 second search: http://in-tools.com/article/scripts-blog/fun-with-text-fitting-in-indesign/ Would this work? If not, why?

Comment: There's a neat script for this called: Fit text to frame. It can be found here: http://www.id-extras.com/products/fit-text-to-frame

Answer (score 3):

Set line to nobreak. Select the merge field and any other text in the line. Go to Justification and set Glyph Scaling minimum to 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of the context but when I encounter similar situations when doing certificates I will use the preview toggle on the DataMerge panel to preview the largest value before I run the merge. Then I adjust the font size so that the largest values fit. Then I will run the merge. This way all the names are formatted consistently.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign does not have built-in functionality to automatically adjust font character size to fit a frame.